# How can I mimic this website effect of an expanding and shrinking popup in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

Please follow the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/default.aspx and see the top right corner of the page.

There you will find a "Microsoft.com" expander. When you move the mouse over it, it displays as a popup and grows. When you move your mouse off of it the window shrinks back. I want to mimic this effect in my WPF application using C#.

Comment: Maybe you want to give your posting a meaningful subject? Thanks!

Comment: I did my best to clean up the question.

Comment: better subject.  What are these people thinking...  subject "need help"...  um, yeah, we all do, thats why we post questions...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're being modded down. You can use a `Popup` control and animate its size.

Comment: Simucal has done a good job making the question understandable. It wasn't like that from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/41742469-ba87-454d-9a02-630f42299811/) at this post at the msdn forum. It explains the use of the popup control a bit. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/27/popup-your-control.aspx)'s another nice example.